# AJAX on liferay portlets

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay, portlet

I am trying to send an AJAX request to a portlet, and it half works. I show you my code and after explain better:

The jQuery AJAX:

```
jQuery("#operation").click(function() 
{
    var url         = '<portlet:resourceURL id="getDataResourceURL"></portlet:resourceURL>';
    var operators   = jQuery('#result').html();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{operators:operators},
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#result').html(data.result);
        }
});
```

And the serveResource

```
@Override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws PortletException, IOException 
{
    String resourceId = resourceRequest.getResourceID();
    if (Validator.isNotNull(resourceId) && resourceId.length() != 0 && resourceId.equalsIgnoreCase("getDataResourceURL"))
    {
        //final String operators = resourceRequest.getParameter("operators");
        String operators = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "operators");

        _log.info("The data from AJAX are: " + operators);

        JSONObject jsonFeed = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();


        jsonFeed.put("result", 8);
        resourceResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        resourceResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resourceResponse.getWriter().write(jsonFeed.toString());
    }
}
```

OK!! What it is working is the response, when I press the input with the id operation the div with id result loads an 8 (that the server response writting on jsonFeed.put("result", 8); The 8 is only for a test). What it is not working is the operators String on _log.info("The data from AJAX are: " + operators); that it is a null (if I use resourceRequest.getParameter("operators");) or an empty string (if I use ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "operators");).

What am I doing wrong? and what can I do to receive this value?

Thank you very much.

PS: On the client side, I tried too this:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, {operators:operators}, function(data) 
{
    jQuery('#result').html(data.result);
});
```

<sub>**PS:** Also posted in [Liferay forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47379844)</sub>

Comment: You are missing "type" attribute in ajax function which defined method type "POST" or "GET". Provide it as `type: "POST"`

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj but it isn´t the solution... it makes the same, it arrives to the server but this can´t take the variables on the request. The String operators (on the java method) is empty or null (it depends about the way used to try get it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change `operators` to say `operators1` so it would look like `{operators1 : operators}`

or

it might be due to namespace, may be you can try having it like

```
data: {"<portlet:namespace />operators" : operators}
```

or

may be try getting the httpRequest in your `serveResource` method code like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(resourceRequest);
String operators = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "operators");
```

Let me know if any of this works

Comment: Thank you @Prakash. I tried at first doing the HttpSerlvetRequest solution and it didn´t work. On the ParamUtil.getString function, I tried before with the argument resourceRequest (exactly as you show), and after with the HttpServletRequest. But no one of both worked. But finally I tried with "<portlet:namepsace />operators" and on the beginning it didn´t work, and the portal showed an error where the portlet must be. It was just a scare, a copy-paste fail... typing quickly you wrote namepsace. When I realized, I changed it and it worked.

Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry about the typo. Corrected. Thanks